# Jquery slider not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have a jquery slider  , when i load the page all div coming together and after sometime it working perfectly .pls try my code....please

This is  the html code i have

is there any way to make this slider as a slide in left  type slider instead of fadeout?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<style>
#slider_one_img{
  float: left;
  background-image: url('one.jpg');
  width: 84px;
height: 86px;
}
#slider_two_img{
float: left;
background-image: url('two.png');
  width: 84px;
height: 86px;
}
#slider_three_img{
  float: left;
  background-image: url('three.jpg');
  width: 84px;
height: 86px;
}
#slider_one_text{

  width:70%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 3%;
  float: left;

}

#slideshow { 
    margin: 68px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 68%; 
    height: 120px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    margin-left: 2%;
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
</style>
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <div id="slider_one_text">My first text</div>
     <div id="slider_one_img"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div id="slider_one_text">My second text...erewrew.r.ewr.eqwr.ewrweqrqewrqwerwerwer
</div>
     <div id="slider_two_img"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div id="slider_one_text">My third text skjsndgnsdkjgndnskgnksngk</div>
     <div id="slider_three_img"></div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`. Your code works fine.
Refer jQuery [Slide Effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/) for sliding left or right.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/y5C4G/7/

Comment: let me check this  ok

Comment: is there any way to put 3 dots representing these slides ,and clicking on dots will show corresponding slide.???

Comment: Yes, you can use any element for that. bind a click event which in return trigger the sliding/fading of slides.

Comment: sorry i'm not so good new jquery..new to this platform..can you help me?

Comment: You can take help from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/y5C4G/8/ Code is simple